# How call methods in servlet without jax-rs?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to call method that you have written in servlet without using jax-rs annotations like GET, POST etc?

Comment: No, You can access the Servlet using only doXXX() methods only.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? It's not clear what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Consider a.com/TestServlet is my servlet address. I want to call aMethod() which is defined inside TestServlet like http://a.com/TestServlet/aMethod or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Consider, a.com/TestServlet is my servlet address I want to call aMethod() which is defined inside TestServlet like a.com/TestServlet/aMethod or something similar to that.

You would need to do this (sort of, this is just a very very basic and naive solution):

1. Have your servlet mapping like: a.com/TestServlet/*
2. In the `doGet` method of your Servlet, retrieve the URL and start partitioning using `/` as delimiter, you will eventually get `"aMethod"` as part of the URL. Then, have a switch (in case of Java SE 7) or another way to parse this *command* to execute of `TestServlet#aMethod` and pass the query by yourself. Of course, I'm just assuming you're doing this for GET requests, but you can also enable it for POST requests as well.

Another way to solve this problem would be using a framework like [restlet](http://restlet.org/) which already handles all this work for you and it's already tested and being maintained periodically instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have considered that there is a simple answer but could not get it. I know there are frameworks to handle this but i have a reason for doing that. I'm creating a library for generating documentation for servlets. Anyway thanks a lot.